# Automatic file transfer (daily)

Tags: php, cron

Is it possible to automaticly download xml files from one server to another server on a daily basis with PHP?

The goal is to create a webapplication in CakePHP which makes use of an xml report that comes from a online accountingserver.

So it can be done using a cronjob? But is cron supported with PHP?

Where can i configure that cronjob?

What kind of code should i write to get the file from the accountingserver in the first place?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559521/automatic-file-transfer-daily

Comment: Why are you using PHP to do a download?  What's wrong with programs like `curl` or `ftp`?  They do a nice job of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Are the servers both running Linux?  Maybe something like [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) would be your best bet, since PHP isn't designed for this kind of task out of the box.

Comment: No.. only one is using linux.. the request for the files goes vy a html request..